# How can I create a list from a single url and append a numerical value to the end of every line

Tags: bash

I need to provide a listing of a website's pages. The only thing to change per line is the page number at the end of the line. So for example, I need to take:

> mywebsite.com/things/stuff/?q=content&page=1

And from that generate a sequential listing of pages:

> - mywebsite.com/things/stuff/?q=content&page=1
> - mywebsite.com/things/stuff/?q=content&page=2
> - mywebsite.com/things/stuff/?q=content&page=3

I need to list all pages between 1 - 120.

I have been using bash but any shell that gets the job done is fine. I don't have any code to show because I simply just don't know how to begin. It sounds simple enough but so far I'm completely at a loss as to how I can accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
for i in $(seq 120); do echo 'mywebsite.com/things/stuff/?q=content&page='"$i"; done > list.txt
```

Comment: or without `seq`: `for ((i=1;i<=120;i++)); do echo 'mywebsite.com/things/stuff/?q=content&page='"$i"; done > list.txt`

Comment: @Cyrus, Thank you for sharing this approach. It is good to know the for loop can handle this "C like syntax". It might be more lightweight than using `seq`.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU bash 4:

```
printf '%s\n' 'mywebsite.com/things/stuff/?q=content&page='{1..120}
```